# How does the scan adverb behave when called with more than one argument?

Tags: kdb

I have two functions both to calculate the exponential weighted moving average. I understand how the first one operates but I am unsure about how the second one gets the same answer.

I am new to `q` and think the answer lies with understanding how the scan function operates when called with multiple arguments. Could someone assist with my understanding of how it handles more than one argument?

```
1)   ewma:{{(y*1-x)+z*x}[x]\[y]}


2)   ewma:{{z+y*x}\[first y;1-x;x*y]}
```

If someone could suggest any resources to guide my understanding of this language other than Q for Mortals and Q Tips then that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The kdb reference card is a really good resource for this kind of thing. The scan and over [page](https://code.kx.com/v2/ref/accumulators) will be good for you.

If you scroll down, you can see how overloaded the scan and over operators are, and how their behaviour changes depending on
1. how many arguments you pass it, and
2. what types those arguments are.

For instance, you can make it behave like a while loop if one of the arguments you pass it is a unary function that returns a boolean, and you can make it act like a do function if the arguments you pass it are an integer and a function.